# osmdroid: animate to current location with pixel offset

Tags: osmdroid

I am trying to achieve an effect like Google Maps and many other (all?) navigation apps: in navigation mode, the current location is displayed *at the bottom* of the screen, so that the user can see more of the road in front of them.

I already have the code to update the location and also change the map's orientation based on the bearing. Everything works perfectly if I keep the map centered on the location, so I am moving on to the offset part. Here is what I have:

```
    if (followMe) {
        float bearing = [...]; // OK until here
        mapView.getController().setCenter(currentLocation); // quickly center on location
        mapView.getController().scrollBy(0, -(int)(mapView.getHeight() / 2 * 0.8)); // shift
        GeoPoint newCenter = mapView.getProjection().getCurrentCenter(); // get the coordinates of the new center
        mapView.getController().animateTo(newCenter, null, (long) 1000, bearing); // center again, this time with a nice animation
    }
```

It does not work as intended and produces weird behaviors: the map is centered elsewhere entirely, updates all of a sudden, etc. I suspect it's because of things like sudden changes in the bearing, or maybe I am just getting it wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The ***MapView.setExpectedCenter()*** method can be used to set the center to a specific location rather than the ***MapView*** projection's default center. This is demonstrated in the OsmDroid demo app's ***Snappable*** sample under the ***Events*** section at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid. The source code for the demo can be found here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/dbb20901cac30b28a6a9349da097c22d9a962311/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/events/SampleSnappable.java

Comment: The method `setExpectedCenter` is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! By the way, while searching for this method, I have finally found an interesting issue as well: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1348 It seems I was not using the right search terms.

Comment: There is documentation in the source code stating that there is no guarantee that it will be working as expected .https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/dbb20901cac30b28a6a9349da097c22d9a962311/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.java#L1829

Comment: Yes, I had noticed it but hoped it would not be a problem. Instead... I am doing `float bearing = [...]; mapView.setMapOrientation(bearing); mapView.setExpectedCenter(currentLocation, 0, (long) (mapView.getHeight() / 2 * 0.7));` Do you see anything wrong? When the bearing changes, the behavior is not correct.

Comment: Try to switch place...do center first and later do the bearing

Comment: For people landing on this page, this is now tracked here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1862